# How to insert a MatPlotLib plot inside of a function when using PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, matplotlib, backend, pysimplegui

I have been working with a few programs and currently am trying to use Matplotlib to put a graph inside an interface made using PySimpleGui.  I have two programs which attempt to plot the same graph, one works, the other doesn't.  I have shown the code below but skipped some of the coding such as imports and 'location' and 'done' so the below can be read easier, but I skipped the same code in both.

The first program is below and correctly opens the graph inside a pysimplegui window.
sg is pysimplegui.

> 

```
fig=gantt(location,done)              #this is defined in another program, and makes the figure

figure_x, figure_y, figure_w, figure_h = fig.bbox.bounds   

layout = [[sg.Text('Plot test', font='Any 18')],  
[sg.Canvas(size=(figure_w, figure_h), key='-CANVAS-')],  
[sg.OK(pad=((figure_w / 2, 0), 3), size=(4, 2))]] 

window = sg.Window('name', layout, force_toplevel=True, finalize=True)  

fig_photo = draw_figure(window['-CANVAS-'].TKCanvas,fig)   
event, values = window.read()  

window.close()
```

The next program does not show the graph.  It has a main window with a button to open a graph window, and the graph window has a graph.  However, there is an error.

```
fig=gantt(location,done) 

figure_x, figure_y, figure_w, figure_h = fig.bbox.bounds


def window_graph(): 
    layout_graph=[
        [sg.Text('graph')],
        [sg.Button('close graph')],
        [sg.Canvas(size=(figure_w, figure_h), key='-CANVAS-')],
    ]
    return sg.Window('graph', layout_graph, margins=(100,50), modal=True)    

fig_photo = draw_figure(window_graph['-CANVAS-'].TKCanvas, fig)                                     

def open_window_graph():    
    graph_window=window_graph()        
    while True:
        event, values = graph_window.read()           
        if event=="close graph" or event==sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            graph_window.close()
            break
        graph_window.close()

layout_main=[
    [sg.Text("first page")],
    [sg.Button('open')],
    [sg.Button('close')]
]

window_main=sg.Window('main',layout_main, margins=(500,400))
while True:
    event,values=window_main.read()
    if event=='open':
         open_window_graph()
    elif event=='close':
       break 
    else:
        break
```

The error I get is;

```
fig_photo = draw_figure(window_graph['-CANVAS-'].TKCanvas, fig)                                     
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

If I remove this line, then the program works except the second window doesn't have a graph.  It is the right size, so I assume the figure_w and figure_h are working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window_graph` is a function name, you can call it by `window_graph()`, and not the `window_graph['-CANVAS-']`, that's why you got `TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable`.

```py
def window_graph(): 
    layout_graph=[
        [sg.Text('graph')],
        [sg.Button('close graph')],
        [sg.Canvas(size=(figure_w, figure_h), key='-CANVAS-')],
    ]
    return sg.Window('graph', layout_graph, margins=(100,50), modal=True)    

fig_photo = draw_figure(window_graph['-CANVAS-'].TKCanvas, fig)
```

Change it to

```py
def window_graph():
    layout_graph=[
        [sg.Text('graph')],
        [sg.Button('close graph')],
        [sg.Canvas(size=(figure_w, figure_h), key='-CANVAS-')],
    ]
    window = sg.Window('graph', layout_graph, margins=(100,50), modal=True)
    fig_photo = draw_figure(window['-CANVAS-'].TKCanvas, fig)
    return window
```